# Line splitting for hashes using regular expressions

Tags: ruby, hash, line, split

I am trying to create a hash bashed off of a file /etc/mime.types in ubuntu for example that splits each line on white space and "not word" regular expression search. Below is my code. but I cannot get it to output the nil valued ones correctly. they out put with everything else  but if you pretty print them with pp some are returning as nil. Any suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
mime = Hash.new()

File.open("/etc/mime.types", "r") do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    next if line[0] == ?#
    next if line == "\n"
    key, value = line.chomp.split(/\W+\s/)
    mime[key] = value
  end
end

if (mime.has_value?('nil') == true)
    mime.sort.each {|key,value| puts "#{key} has no extensions."}
elsif(mime.has_value?('nil') == false)
    mime.sort.each {|key, value| puts "#{key} has extensions #{value}"}
end
```

This is only the tail end of the output which is easiest to see since its right in front when you execute

I expect

```
video/quicktime has extensions qt mov
**video/vnd.fvt has no extensions** 
**video/vnd.motorola.video has no extensions 
video/vnd.motorola.videop has no extensions** 
video/vnd.mpegurl has extensions mxu
**video/vnd.mts has no extensions no**
video/vnd.nokia.interleaved-multimedia has extensions 
**video/vnd.vivo has no extensions** 
video/x-flv has extensions flv
video/x-la-asf has extensions lsf lsx
video/x-matroska has extensions mpv mkv
video/x-mng has extensions mng
video/x-ms-asf has extensions asf asx
video/x-ms-wm has extensions wm
video/x-ms-wmv has extensions wmv
video/x-ms-wmx has extensions wmx
video/x-ms-wvx has extensions wvx
video/x-msvideo has extensions avi
video/x-sgi-movie has extensions movie
x-conference/x-cooltalk has extensions ice
x-epoc/x-sisx-app has extensions sisx
x-world/x-vrml has extensions vrm vrml wrl
```

but i get

```
video/quicktime has extensions qt mov
video/vnd.fvt has extensions 
video/vnd.motorola.video has extensions 
video/vnd.motorola.videop has extensions 
video/vnd.mpegurl has extensions mxu
video/vnd.mts has extensions 
video/vnd.nokia.interleaved-multimedia has extensions 
video/vnd.vivo has extensions 
video/x-flv has extensions flv
video/x-la-asf has extensions lsf lsx
video/x-matroska has extensions mpv mkv
video/x-mng has extensions mng
video/x-ms-asf has extensions asf asx
video/x-ms-wm has extensions wm
video/x-ms-wmv has extensions wmv
video/x-ms-wmx has extensions wmx
video/x-ms-wvx has extensions wvx
video/x-msvideo has extensions avi
video/x-sgi-movie has extensions movie
x-conference/x-cooltalk has extensions ice
x-epoc/x-sisx-app has extensions sisx
x-world/x-vrml has extensions vrm vrml wrl
```

Comment: Can you please list out the output you are expecting, and the output you are getting, for a sample file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string `'nil'` and the object `nil` are not the same thing. Your `mime.has_value?('nil')` is asking the Hash if one of its values is the string `'nil'`, not the object `nil`. You (think you) want this:

```
if(mime.has_value?(nil))
  mime.sort.each {|key,value| puts "#{key} has no extensions."}
else
  mime.sort.each {|key, value| puts "#{key} has extensions #{value}"}
end
```

And [`has_value?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-has_value-3F) returns `true` or `false` so you don't need to compare its return value against `true` and `false`, just `if(mime.has_value?(nil)) ... else` is sufficient.

But that still won't give you what you're looking for. Your `if` will claim that **all** keys have no extensions if at least one of them doesn't and that doesn't make much sense. You want to iterate over `mime` with something like this:

```
mime.each do |k, v|
  if(v.nil?)
    puts "#{k} has no extensions"
  else
    puts "#{k} has extensions #{v}"
  end
end
```

Comment: You sir are a genius. I did not even consider iterate over the hash.
I pulled a buddy in on this who couldn't get it either.

Comment: @Spartan-196: The hardest things to see are often the ones right in front of your face :)